# Regarding perl dbd oracle

Tags: perl

I have two queries

1. When i run the below perl script i am getting the below error

`Unable to connect: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified (DBD ERROR: OCIServerAttach)`

I can't modify  the tnsnames.ora as i dont have access.  I know tnsnames.ora doesn't have a entry for testdb database. Is there a workaround. Thought i am accessing the database in the remote solaris machine with the IP Address so no need of a entry in the local solaris machine tnsnames.ora.

```
$platform = "Oracle";
$database = "testdb";
$host = "testdb.dev.test.com.au";
$port = "2000";
$user = "scott";
$pw = "tiger";


$dsn = "dbi:$platform:$database:$host:3306";
print "$dsn" . "\n";

# PERL DBI CONNECT (RENAMED HANDLE)
my $dbstore = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pw) or die "Unable to connect: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

2 My understanding about DBD module is even oracle is not installed in the local machine DBD module should work.  But i noticed while installation it uses oracle client libraries. So if i install a DBD::Sybase do i need to have a installation of sysbase in local machine. Since I am accessing remote server database thought why local installation of oracle/sybase libraries are required?

Comment: can any one help me out for the second query?

Comment: Please check my comment in my answer for your second question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your dsn syntax is wrong. try to make it look like below:

```
$dsn = "dbi:$platform:host=$host;sid=$sid;port=$port";
```

Above syntax has worked for me in numerous cases where I had used `DBD::Oracle`.

Comment: Thanks a  lot.  It works now. could you pls have  a look at my second question about the installation of DBD Module.

Comment: DBD needs a local client installed prior to installing relevant perl module. for oracle, You need to install and configure Oracle instant client prior installing `DBD::Oracle` and for MSSQL, you need to install and configure `unixodbc` and `freetds` before installing `DBD::ODBC`. Meaning, a local client needs to have configured and should be able to access the database. So I am pretty sure there has to be a local client needed for DB2 before you think of installing relevant DBD perl module for DB2.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Thought perl DBD will have all the libraries for connecting to oracle.